# EC2 Linux instance crashes every few hours

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2

I have installed a WordPress site in AWS EC2 t3.micro on platform Linux/UNIX. The ec2 instance stops responding every few hours. That means if I try to call the website from the browser I get  "This site can't be reached" message. The site starts to work again if I reboot the instance from the ec2 console. The inbound rules for HTTP and HTTPS set to 0.0.0.0/0. There is a number of website visitors. There is 4.2G available space on the EC2 instance. The latest error log entries are:

```
[Tue Jul 12 09:01:50.142638 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 566] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 12 09:01:50.142711 2022] [core:notice] [pid 566] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 12 10:23:11.216290 2022] [php:warn] [pid 1077] [client X.X.X.X:57861] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "referrer" in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/classes/form-record.php on line 179, referer: https://SITE-NAME-REMOVED/contact-us/
[Tue Jul 12 10:23:11.217667 2022] [php:warn] [pid 1077] [client X.X.X.X:57861] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "referrer" in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/classes/form-record.php on line 179, referer: https://SITE-NAME-REMOVED/contact-us/
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found


[Mon Jul 11 00:00:01.527769 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 570] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 11 00:00:01.527800 2022] [core:notice] [pid 570] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 11 13:44:17.339898 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 577] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 11 13:44:17.347833 2022] [core:notice] [pid 577] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 11 13:44:26.721451 2022] [php:warn] [pid 727] [client x.X.x.x:35130] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "referrer" in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/classes/form-record.php on line 179, referer: https://SITE-NAME-REMOVED/contact-us/
[Mon Jul 11 13:44:26.722285 2022] [php:warn] [pid 727] [client x.x.x.x:35130] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "referrer" in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/classes/form-record.php on line 179, referer: https://SITE-NAME-REMOVED/contact-us/
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
[Mon Jul 11 14:37:11.427820 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 577] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 11 17:32:49.756249 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 600] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 11 17:32:49.756835 2022] [core:notice] [pid 600] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 11 20:15:40.358852 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 600] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: Can you please check the CPU utilisation and see if it is not crossing the baseline performance of the instance. Since the reboot is able to fix the issue, It seems it is a resource crunch issue.

Comment: It seems like that's Apache's log. Output of ``dmesg`` would be helpful. I guess the reason is OOM, but it's hard to tell anything more without further information.